# All namespaces in one line

Tags: c++, clang-format

How can I achieve that all namespaces are in one line, so that this

[image]

becomes this

[image]

These are my clang format settings:

```
---
AccessModifierOffset: '0'
IndentWidth: '4'
BreakBeforeBraces: Linux
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: 'false'
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
TabWidth: '4'
UseTab: Always
ColumnLimit: 0
...
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible unless you dig into the syntactical stuff

Comment: What do you mean by 'dig into the syntactical stuff'?

Answer (score 0):

You can't; from the [clangformat page](https://clangformat.com/) the only thing you can change is the indentation.

I suspect it's not a particularly common desire to put everything on one line as it becomes harder to ensure that your {} line up.